# How to calculate the theoretical probability of a 10 sided die

Tags: probability-theory

How do you solve for the theoretical probability of getting a roll of 6 or more in a single roll of a 10 sided dice?

Answer (score 1):

Probability of an event is the favorable number of outcomes, divided by the total number of outcomes.

How many outcomes are there for a roll of a 10 sided dice? How many of those outcomes result in a 6 or higher?

There are obviously 10 outcomes on the roll of the dice, it could land on any of the 10 sides. There are 5 ways it can land on a 6 or higher (6,7,8,9,10).

So $\frac{5}{10} = \frac{1}{2} = .5$